# Bat script to retrieve folder size (windows)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to write a script .bat that give me the free space of a certain disk and the detail of all folders with the relative dimension and write it in a simple text file (just to check the distribution of used space).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the mistake...I don't use Stack Overflow so much then I don't actually know your rules :)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
dir /a /s | findstr /b /c:" " > file.txt
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answer, I'm doing some test but i still have a problem...
My goal is to analyse a Disk (G:\) and create a txt showing directories and dimensions for every directory, e.g.:

Folder1 --> 5Gb
Folder2 --> 6Gb
Folder3 --> 4Kb

etc...

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The FileSystemObject can do this for you. It is accessible from PowerShell (among other sources).

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "$fso = New-Object -COMObject Scripting.FileSystemObject; Get-ChildItem YOUR_ROOT_DIRECTORY -Recurse -Directory | %% { $f = $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName); '{0},{1}' -f $f.Size,$_.FullName };"
```